# What is the significance of sacrificing animals in front of God?

Tags: sacrifice

Can anyone kindly tell me the significance of sacrificing animals (like goat) in front of God/Goddess? During Durga Puja I have seen that people sacrifice different things (aka "Balidan") in front of God/Goddess.

Also I have seen 108 lights are offered after the sacrifice. I would love to know the meaning for that.

Pranam.

Comment: The practice of sacrifice (especially in Shakta tantra) comes from *Kaula* vidhis of Puja. Tantra is an alternate mode of worship of deities. The particular sect - *vamachara* has rites of *panchamakara* or 5 Ms : 1. Mamsa (Meat), 2. Matsya (fish), 3. madya (alcohol, wine), 4. mudra (cereal), 5. mudra (hand gestures). Note: There are specific procedures of Bali (either though cut of a blade or mantra spell to kill) and the deity blesses both: the animal as well as the vyadha (butcher) for it. Although, Bali has been in Vedas too what you are referring to is tantric.

Comment: Thanks ! But what I wanted to know is the Significance - what spiritual benefit happens when someone offers "Balidan"? Is this related to the 6 Ripus of human somehow (Kam, Krodh, . . . etc.) ?

Comment: The *significance* actually varies a lot. In tantra the goal is to become one with the deity. In Ugra practices (like sacrifices in this case) - ugra (or aghora) deities like - durga, Kali (shamshan kali specially), Bhairava, etc like deities are worshipped, where the end goal is to get *possessed* (or become one with the deity). I'm not sure if this is the case with Durga Puja, but in the usual sense - a lot of tantra sadhana is sensitive because of such cases. Such possession which brings enlightenment to the sadhak is the chief goal and liberates him.